# acess multiple http/s ports via subdirectories of port 80/443 with apache2

Tags: ubuntu, http, apache-http-server, https

My problem is, that I have server applications using http but running on port 9001 for example. As I have webapplications running on port 80 and port 443 I can't simply change the configuration of the server application to use those ports, so I want for example `http://localhost/application` on port 80 internally connect to `http://localhost:9001` as I don't want to forward port 9001 in my router.

When searching for a solution I found something about using a reverse proxy but didn't really understand it and don't know if this is the right solution.

Additionally it would be nice to map `http://localhost:9001` to `https://localhost` with automatic SSL-encryption with my own certificate, because the server application doesn't support SSL on it's own.

I'm running Ubuntu server 12.04 with apache2.

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html). Please read the good documentation on the apache site to configure it.

This allows you to use your apache as *reverse proxy* in front of another web application server like tomcat, another apache or some kind of other applications.

This allows you also to terminate a ssl connection on the apache server and speak plain http to the backend.

Comment: How do I use and configure it?

Comment: @FSMaxB see the link above